# Emails go to spam folder Laravel and VestaCP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I want to use VestaCP mail server with Laravel, emails will go to spam folder.

I configured Laravel .env file like this

`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

`MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.tld`

`MAIL_PORT=25`

`MAIL_USERNAME=noreplay@mydomain.tld`

`MAIL_PASSWORD=******`

`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`

When I try to use Roundcube to send emails they will go to inbox, but with Laravel application, it goes to spam folder!

Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Nothing to do with the app, but outgoing mail server and inbound server spam-protection.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for sending e-mails with laravel is using Mailgun